# How to specify .NET version when using /CLR option

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, compilation, c++-cli, clr

I am compiling third party C++ code using /CLR flag which requires only .NET Framework 3.5.

The code is getting compiled fine, but since I have .NET 4.0 installed on my dev box the resulting binary doesn't work for any .NET framework less than 4.0

So, how do I tell Visual Studio to use a particular version of the .NET Framework while compiling?

Comment: In the solution explorer right click the project.
The project page will appear and from there you can choose your Target Framework.

Comment: Here's a reference, it pertains to web projects but the theory should be the same.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398791.aspx#additional_information

Comment: I don't get the option. I just see "Target Framework" as 4.0. Note that it is C++ application. If it was C# application, it would have been different

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quoting an article on the [Visual C++ Team Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/), [Visual Studio 2010 C++ Project Upgrade Guide](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2010/03/02/visual-studio-2010-c-project-upgrade-guide/):

> ... the VS2010 compiler cannot target Framework 2.0, 3.0 or 3.5. The VS2008 compiler must be used to target 2.0, 3.0 or 3.5. ... The C++ applications can be retargeted to other frameworks (say 3.5 for example) by one of the following methods:
>
> - Edit the vcxproj file and in the first property group define add the following: `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>`
> - Open the VS2010 command line, `set TargetFrameworkVersion=v3.5`, and then start devenv.exe from the commandline. This will target all your C++ applications to v3.5 framework.
> - Pass `/p:TargetFrameworkVersion=v3.5` to MSBuild when building applications: `MSBuild my.vcxproj /p:TargetFrameworkVersion=v3.5`
>
> Note that VS2008 has to be installed on the machine for the application to target 2.0, 3.0 or 3.5.